# C# Creating Collection Out of 2 Arrays In different Class. Use Linq to Select/From

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, inheritance, collections

Here's my problem.  I have 2 arrays that are like this.

```
    string[] fruit1 = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Grape", "Kiwi" };
        string[] fruit2 = { "Peach", "Nectarine", "Banana", "Cherry" };
```

I was asked to create a second class.  Add a "couple slightly different properties".  Then use Linq to Select/From the first class to create a sorted collection in the second class that gets rid of the duplicate ("Banana").

Here's what I've worked out, before being told that I needed to incorporate the second class, and the select/from.  The sorts are there as a part of the assignment.  They work fine.  And this program works fine.  The only thing was, after I sent it, I was told the whole part of the second class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MergeArray
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fruit1 = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Grape", "Kiwi" };
        string[] fruit2 = { "Peach", "Nectarine", "Banana", "Cherry" };
        string[] fruit3 = new string[fruit1.Length + fruit2.Length];

        string temp;

        foreach (string i in fruit1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fruit1.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(fruit1[j], fruit1[j + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    temp = fruit1[j];
                    fruit1[j] = fruit1[j + 1];
                    fruit1[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (string i in fruit2)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fruit2.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(fruit2[j], fruit2[j + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    temp = fruit2[j];
                    fruit2[j] = fruit2[j + 1];
                    fruit2[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        fruit1.CopyTo(fruit3, 0);
        fruit2.CopyTo(fruit3, names1.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, fruit3.Distinct().ToArray()));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

So my question is.  How would I pass these first 2 arrays into an outside class, so I could then use them to create the constructor (fruit3) in the outside class?  Then after that, return the new constructor to display the new merged/sorted constructor (without duplicates) of "Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Nectarine", "Peach" ?

Comment: You keep talking about classes, but I see none in your code, apart from the Program class... Hurry up and tidy your question before it gets closed for not being clear enough.

Comment: I'm sorry.  The code was more of an example of the output I was trying to get.  I haven't made the other class because I don't get how to pass the arrays into the new class.  If I put one in, it would just be empty.  I'm sorry if my question is not clear.  I'm just looking for help in trying to be able to pass the first two arrays into a second class, to be defined.

Comment: First step towards getting help is asking the right question.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea Okay, allow me to clarify.  And again, I apologize that my question was unclear.  I need to be able to create a new class, with two "slightly different properties" (that was what was given to me, it's what I have to go on, I'm sorry).  Anyway, in this new class, I need to be able to create a collection out of the two arrays (fruit1 and fruit2), using Linq select/from.  I was told using reflection should help, but everything I look up doesn't really help me in the case of passing the arrays to the second (as yet undefined) class.  Then merging them into the collection.

Comment: The first 2 arrays (fruit1 and fruit2) need to be defined outside of the scope of the second class that I need to make.  But I need to be able to pass their values to the second class to be able to create the collection.  The arrays need to be sorted (the way I have it) separately.  I actually messed up in the original question (clarified in my edit).  They are sorted separately, then merged together, without sorting the final collection, which is how it needs to be.  My main problem is just doing all of the merging in the second class.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. Perhaps someone else could understand.

Comment: For the merge see Xiaoy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Concat`, `Distinct` and `OrderBy` :

```
string[] fruit3 = 
    // concat these 2 togather
    fruit1.Concat(fruit2)
        // remove any duplicates
        .Distinct()
        // order them
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        // finally, converts IEnumerable<string> to string[]
        .ToArray();
```

---

As for *using them outside of class*, you need to move them outside of `Main()` method. As local variable cannot be accessed anywhere other than within the declaring method, unless you pass it as via parameter. You also need to prefix them with the [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) , [`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx), as you need to access them outside of `Program` class, as such :

```
class Program
{
    public string[] fruit1 = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Grape", "Kiwi" };
    public string[] fruit2 = { "Peach", "Nectarine", "Banana", "Cherry" };

    // ...
}
```

> The public keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Public access is the most permissive access level. There are no
>   restrictions on accessing public members.

EDIT 2: There is many way that to have the Names class to do this. Here is an example :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fruit1 = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Grape", "Kiwi" };
        string[] fruit2 = { "Peach", "Nectarine", "Banana", "Cherry" };
        string[] fruit3 = Names.UniqueSortedJoin(fruit1, fruit2);
    }
}

class Names
{
    public static string[] UniqueSortedJoin(string[] names1, string[] names2)
    {
        return names1.Concat(names2)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not sure that helps in doing it in an outside class.  I've tried using your example, by moving the two arrays outside main, then creating a new class  as (I don't know how to do code in comments, so bare with me)  public class Names{  }.  Then trying to use your example on the top inside the Names class.  it also doesn't help with my confusion on the need for me to use two properties in the Names class (which was needed per the person who assigned me this) before I fill the collection.

Comment: How would I be able to do that in the Names class, is my question.  So I have the "Program" class where all the code for the arrays and the sorting of the arrays are, then I need to have the "Names" class to take the two arrays and merge them into the collection.

Comment: While it's not exactly what I was trying to do, all I had to do was get rid of the ".OrderBy(x =< x)" and it displayed what I was looking for.  But more importantly, it answered my question about passing arrays into and out of outside classes.  Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Oh... I did that because you mentioned "merged/*sorted* constructor".